# How to add has_many association to two different model in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

How can i accomplish this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
  has_many :old_posts
  has_many :new_posts
end
```

I already have has_many relation to old_posts model. I would like to add another has_many relation to new_posts. The old_posts and new_posts are no way related. I'm in the process of refactoring my schema, I would like to support the 'old_posts' model for few months before I get rid of it totally.

I get this error in schema when I try to migrate

```
#Could not dump table "Users" because of 
following NoMethodError
#undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: What ur expecting when u call old_post and new_post?    I mean conditions

Answer (score 1):

- You should specify conditions as both are referring to same model.
- Mention model it's referring to explicitly as it won't identify model by default because of custom association names.

Update code like below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :old_posts, ->{where("created_at > ?", Time.now.end_of_day)}, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: 'user_id'
    has_many :new_posts, ->{where("created_at < ?", Time.now.end_of_day)}, class_name: 'Post',foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

Comment: I'm using two different models 'old_posts' and 'new_posts' and these models now have different columns.

Comment: @Lollypop u mean different foreign key?

Comment: No, it's completely different table and model.

Comment: @Lollypop why u created two models with same attributes ?

Comment: Different columns and attributes they have.

Comment: @Lollypop then issue might be with your migration files. paste migration file which created recently for which u facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The schema dump issue was due to my ignorance. I was using bool instead of boolean.